# Google Sitemap generates errors

Tags: magento-1.9, sitemaps

When I manually **Generate** sitmap.xml from admin's Catalog>Google Sitemap, it throws the following error in the browser:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@TheDomain.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**Apache error_log**

```
[Fri Dec 25 10:15:12 2015] [error] [client HostIP] client denied by server configuration: /home/DIRECTORY/public_html/MAGENTO/app/etc/local.xml  
[Fri Dec 25 10:26:07 2015] [error] [client MyIP] Script timed out before returning headers: index.php, referer: https://TheDomain/sitemap/index/key/e6...22/  
[Fri Dec 25 10:31:35 2015] [error] [client MyIP] Script timed out before returning headers: index.php, referer: https://TheDomain/cms_page/index/key/56...9c/  
[Fri Dec 25 10:41:07 2015] [error] [client MyIP] Script timed out before returning headers: index.php, referer: https://TheDomain/sitemap/index/key/e6...22/  
[Fri Dec 25 10:46:35 2015] [error] [client MyIP] Script timed out before returning headers: index.php, referer: https://TheDomain/cms_page/index/key/56...9c/  
[Fri Dec 25 10:47:40 2015] [error] [client HostIP] client denied by server configuration: /home/DIRECTORY/public_html/MAGENTO/app/etc/local.xml  
[Fri Dec 25 10:47:52 2015] [error] [client HostIP] client denied by server configuration: /home/DIRECTORY/public_html/MAGENTO/app/etc/local.xml  
[Fri Dec 25 11:13:04 2015] [notice] SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart    
[Fri Dec 25 11:13:05 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...  
[Fri Dec 25 11:13:05 2015] [notice] Digest: done  
[Fri Dec 25 11:13:06 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `www.DOMAIN.com' does NOT match server name!?  
[Fri Dec 25 11:13:06 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips DAV/2 mod_bwlimited/1.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

This could be a browser time out issue!

Can this command be executed from shell ssh?

Comment: Can you attach the error log?

Comment: Which error log? `error_log` located at the root?

Comment: The web server error log.. in **apache:** `/var/log/apache/error.log`, in **nginx:** `/var/log/nginx/error.log` however both logs can be overridden for  each vhost definition, so you must first find the log error file, have you access to your server filesystem?

Comment: I found it under `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log`.  Posted it up above.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems to be a timeout problem, but could be a write permissions problem too, so just to be sure:

1. Try to switch to webserver user ie: `$ su www-data`
2. Then try to write a file in magento root folder (as same level as index.php) ie: `$ touch [magento_root]/test-file`

If these validation steps are ok, try to change the php timeouts (you can change these values just for admin request) [here](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/apache-and-php-limits-and-timeouts) you will find a guide about changing php timeouts and other limitations.

However you would be able to perform sitemap.xml generation automatically if you have a system cronjob configured and pointed to magento cron.php/sh file, and properly configured in backend:

[image]

Comment: sitemap.xml gets generated via a cronjob without any problems!  But once in while i need to generate the sitemap.xml at will.  Is there any way to generate the sitemap.xml through shell?

Comment: sitemap shell generation isn't a feature in magento "out of the box". I don't know if you can do it with [link]https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun, however, you would be able to change the timeouts or reconfigure the cronjob time to a few minutes from now  (just as workaround), as i say before

Comment: That's a good idea to temporarily change the cronjob execution.

Comment: Just now the sitemap.xml got rebuild / got genrated.  It started at 10:05am and finished at 1:30pm, almost 3.5 hours.  So the browser timed out, but the process was kept live and active. sitemap.xml files size is 890,862. Is that amount of time normal for sitemap.xml generation?

Comment: wooow 3.5hs it's a lot of time!!! Well if your generation process take such amount of time the backend(browser) on-demand generation isn't possible to adjust. I've been working with some big sites with more than 100K skus and around 10 websites so... many URLs, but i never saw a 3.5 hours sitemap process... how many skus/websites are in your store?

Comment: Exactly what was bothering me as well.  This store has only one website and about 23K skus, plus roughly around 50-70 CMS pages.

Comment: Ok this is just an ugly workaround, but if you don't have any manual-made rewrites you could try to truncate the `core_url_rewrite` table and then run the url-rewrites indexer to regenerate them. Before that execute in mysql:  `select count(*) from core_url_rewrite`  in order to measure the amount of urls you will to write to sitmaps.xml a logic number (about count) could be: )amount of skus * 3 + amount of categories * amount of nested levels + amoutn of cms pages) if the resulft (of count()) is far higher than that qty truncate and regenerate the table would be a nice solution.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank you and happy holidays.

Comment: Good luck!!! and don't forget to backup data before truncate :)